# Chef BVT recipe needs to run only application deployment is performed

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have preapred BVT (automation recipe) which will run on the client server as part of every chef-client but we need to modify it like , BVT recipe needs to trigger only for the application deployment not for the other configruation changes .

Please let me know how to perform this

Answer (score 0):

The way we did follow is to use a databag to set a deploy_allowed flag and a helper method within our deployment recipe wich test if it is allowed to deploy or not.

The helper method looks like (in french sorry):

```
module Company
  def can_deploy?(bag, env, name)
    liv = data_bag_item(bag, env)
    msg = "Aucune entree trouvee, * ou #{name} pour l'environnement #{env}, deploiement refuse."
    liv_allowed = false
    entry = nil

    entry = '*' if liv.include?('*')
    entry = name if liv.include?(name)

    unless entry.nil?
      liv_allowed = true if liv[entry] == 'true'
      msg = "Deploiement #{liv_allowed ? 'autorise' : 'refuse'} par l'entree #{entry} de #{env}"
    end
    Chef::Log.info(msg)
    liv_allowed
  end
end

Chef::Recipe.send(:include, Company)
Chef::Resource.send(:include, Company)
Chef::Provider.send(:include, Company)
```

and the Databag item looks like (in json):

```
{
  "id": "I1",
  "*": "false",
  "I1FR1WAS01": "true",
  "I1FR1WAS02": "false",
  "I1FR1WAS03": "false",
  "I1FR1WAS04": "false"
}
```

Inside the recipe we do call it like that:

```
if !can_deploy?("datab_bag",node.chef_environment,node.name) return
```

In this exemple the chef_environment for the node is I1 and its name is I1R1WAS01, which allow it to deploy but not the others servers.

I hope it could help you adapt it to your needs. Don't hesitate to comment if its unclear.